# Google Calendar reminder for every other day except Saturday and Sunday

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

How do I create a reminder for every other day except Saturday and Sunday?

```
           M T W TTH F Sa Su
1st Week   *   *     *
2nd Week     *    *   
3rd Week   *   *     *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done as two repeated events, rather than one. Create two identically named events, one of which happens on MWF every other week, and the other on TTH of every other week, starting a week later.

[image: repeat every 2 weeks]

Answer (score -1):

Google calendar has been added two new options to the Repeats drop down list:

[image: Google calendar repeat options]

So you can pick one of them.

Comment: I can't see your screenshot, could you give me the step by step guide on how to go to that?

Comment: I just replaced the image. Can you see the image now?

Comment: Companies often block image sharing services. (For instance, I can't see your image now, although the Stack Exchange Imgur URL isn't yet blocked.) An image is great, but it would be better to also include the text of the two new options you're talking about.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP wants MWF one week, then TTh the second week, then MWF the third week, etc.

Comment: but it seems https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/93448/126681 was the answer! which is not what they asked.